# How to access Unix passwd file from Apache when using .htaccess?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, password, pam

Is it possible to use the system passwd file for accessing a protected web page with Apache on Linux?  Setting up multiple password files for shell access, Apache and Samba is a pain.  If there is a mod for that, it would be handy to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_auth_external (http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) can be configured to auth against /etc/shadow

Comment: This is made of WIN. You're running another daemon as root, but it should be simple enough to be sure there's no security problems with it.

Answer (score 4):

### mod_auth_pam

[mod_auth_pam](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/) is the standard method on most UNIX systems and apache.

- [Full Docs and examples](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/configure.html)
- [FAQ](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/faq.html)

### Example:

#### Configure PAM

Here’s what the */etc/pam.d/httpd* looks like (could be different on your distro)

```
auth required pam_unix.so
auth required pam_unix.so
account required pam_unix.so
```

#### Configure Apache

```
AuthPAM_Enabled on
AllowOverride None
AuthName "secure area"
AuthType "basic"
```

Comment: How does this work without putting www-data in the shadow group?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't. FAIL.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a module that works with mod_perl to do exactly what you're asking: [Apache-AuthenPasswd-0.12](http://search.cpan.org/~speeves/Apache-AuthenPasswd-0.12/AuthenPasswd.pm)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible---yes.  However, I'm not sure that this is a really good idea from a security standpoint.  I thought that there is a lot of information out there saying not to directly link the system passwd information as an authentication source.

Another possibility (with a lot of effort and planning) is to implement LDAP.

Comment: I would still like to know how to implement LDAP.  It seems more difficult than it should be.